# Go backward by N levels using setwd() in R

Tags: r, directory, path, cd, setwd

is there a way to go back in the directory using the R function `setwd()` by different levels?

for e.g.

```
> getwd() 
  /home/folder1/folder2/
```

I want to arrive in home in just one shot without typing `setwd("../..")`. It is very tedious to write n times "../"

Comment: You can come to *home* with `setwd("~")` at least on *UNIX*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create the path `"../.."` dynamically.

```
setwd_n_levels <- function(n) {
  setwd(paste0(rep('..', n), collapse = '/'))
}

setwd_n_levels(2)
getwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strrep`

```
setwd_n_levels <- function(n) {
   setwd(trimws(strrep('../', n), whitespace = '/'))
  }
```